# #1005 - mysql - can't create a foreign key

Tags: mysql

I created this table here:

```
CREATE TABLE izpulnitel(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
ime VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
familia VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
img BLOB
);
```

and this other table:

```
CREATE TABLE album(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
godina INT(6) NULL,
opisanie TEXT
);
```

and I want to creat a third table with 2 foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE pesen (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ime VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    tekst TEXT,
    izpulnitel_id INT(6),
    album_id INT(6),

    INDEX par_ind  (izpulnitel_id),
    INDEX par_indx (album_id),

    FOREIGN KEY (izpulnitel_id) 
        REFERENCES izpulnitel(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,

    FOREIGN KEY (album_id) 
        REFERENCES album(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

But for some reason the table can't be created. There is some kind of error around the foreign key operators, most likely it's the INDEX tag.

I tried adding seperate queries with `CREATE INDEX ...` but it doesn't seem to work. Should I have created these indexes with the created of the parent tables or there is another solution? What are these INDEX-s made for anyway ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating foreign keys it is extremely important(read: required) that the columns being used are of the same types.

From the MySQL documentation:

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same.

Your id columns in the first two tables are INT UNSIGNED, but the izpulnitel_id  and album_id in your 3rd table are INT(i.e signed). Signedness is one of the things that must match. Change those columns to INT(6) UNSIGNED and you should be on your way.

The indexes are there for performance reasons. Again from the MySQL documentation:

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE pesen ( id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, ime VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, tekst TEXT, izpulnitel_id INT(6) UNSIGNED, album_id INT(6) UNSIGNED, INDEX par_ind (izpulnitel_id), INDEX par_indx (album_id), FOREIGN KEY (izpulnitel_id) REFERENCES izpulnitel(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (album_id) REFERENCES album(id) ON DELETE CASCADE )
```

Comment: You were missing the UNSIGNED in child table attributes ,  which was defined in parent table ,